# Silverlight "Add Service Reference" to ASP Service error

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf, rest

I'm not sure what's causing this error.

The service markup:

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Language="C#" 
    Debug="true" 
    Service="WebRole1.ExpenseService" 
    CodeBehind="ExpenseService.svc.cs"
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
%>
```

The service code behind:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ExpenseService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="expenses", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public List<ExpenseInfo> GetExpenses()
    {
        List<ExpenseInfo> result = new List<ExpenseInfo>();
        // ...

        return result;
    }
}
```

If I run the project and navigate to the service on the browser, the data shows up fine.

If I try to add the service `http://localhost:88/ExpenseService.svc/expenses`, I get the error:

> The document at the url
>   http://localhost:88/ExpenseService.svc/expenses
>   was not recognized as a known document
>   type.
>
> The error message from each known type
>   may help you fix the problem:
>
> - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema
>     should be  and its namespace
>     should be
>     'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.
> - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL
>     http://localhost:88/ExpenseService.svc/expenses
>     could not be found.'.
> - The document format is not recognized.
> - Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (1,
>     2).'.
>
>   - was not expected.
>
> Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:88/ExpenseService.svc/expenses'.
>
> The remote server returned an
>   unexpected response: (405) Method Not
>   Allowed.
>
> The remote server returned an error:
>   (405) Method Not Allowed.
>
> If the service is defined in the
>   current solution, try building the
>   solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

If I try to add a service reference to `http://localhost:88/ExpenseService.svc`, I get the error:

> There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:88/ExpenseService.svc'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
>   'http://localhost:88/ExpenseService.svc'.
>   There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:88/ExpenseService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: This page might be useful: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure/Wiki/View.aspx?title=KnownIssues

**Update 2**: I tried what was suggested on that site, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had originally made the reference as AJAX enabled. I deleted it and made a typical WCF one, and it seems to be working. (Although I'm still getting `SecurityException` issues, as detailed in another question of mine.)